# How to create a new object from existing object using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below object

```
   $scope.projectDetails = [
  {
    "pName": "A",
    "projectTime": [
      {
        "month": "2"
      },
      {
        "month": "3"
      },
      {
        "month": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "pName": "B",
    "projectTime": [
      {
        "month": "2"
      },
      {
        "month": "3"
      },
      {
        "month": "4"
      },
      {
        "month": "5"
      },
      {
        "month": "6"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i am  trying to push 12 months inside projectTime array.
I am trying to build the object below:

```
[
      {
        "pName" : "A",
        "projectTime": [
          {
            "month": "1"
          },
          {
            "month": "2"
          },
          {
            "month": "3"
          },
          {
            "month": "4"
          },
          {
            "month": "5"
          },
          {
            "month": "6"
          },
          {
            "month": "7"
          },
          {
            "month": "8"
          },
          {
            "month": "9"
          },
          {
            "month": "10"
          },
          {
            "month": "11"
          },
          {
            "time": "0"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "pName" : "B",
        "projectTime": [
          {
            "month": "1"
          },
          {
            "month": "2"
          },
          {
            "month": "3"
          },
          {
            "month": "4"
          },
          {
            "month": "5"
          },
          {
            "month": "6"
          },
          {
            "month": "7"
          },
          {
            "month": "8"
          },
          {
            "month": "9"
          },
          {
            "month": "10"
          },
          {
            "month": "11"
          },
          {
            "time": "0"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

And below is my code and tried to implement this but I couldn't.

```
angular.forEach($scope.projectDetails, function(value, key) { 
    for(var i=1; i < 13; i++) {
        angular.forEach(value.projectTime, function(projectTimeValue, projectTimeKey) {
            if(projectTimeValue.month != 1) {
                value.projectTime.splice(0,0, {

                    "month": "1"
                })
            }

            if(projectTimeValue.month != 2) {
                value.projectTime.splice(1,0, {

                    "month": "2"
                })
            }

            if(projectTimeValue.month != 3) {
                value.projectTime.splice(2,0, {

                    "month": "3"
                })
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Here I am trying to do first loop and in the second loop I am trying to splice the object in a specific index. Here `$scope.projectDetails` root array and `$scope.projectDetails.projectTime` sub JSON array.

Comment: You should look up definition of "JSON", because you don't seem to have any in your question at all. You seem to just mean you have an "object"...

Comment: You don't have a valid JSON

Comment: please check again. i have changed the JSON